# Is headless ubuntu server more stable than ubuntu desktop with x server?

Tags: server, desktop-environments

Currently I have to decide whether to install either ubuntu desktop or ubuntu server onto the pc systems of our customers.

Could you share your experience with us? Which one is more stable (less freezing) for production environment?

Our end customer won't need to ever login onto the server since it will be running without a monitor and without input devices. We will remote control the server via teamviewer/anydesk.

Comment: This is a wrong place to ask for opinions and experience. This is a Q&A site.

Comment: There are a lot less services running on a server with no GUI. While this might put on hold as opinion based, myself I think server, by far. I would only consider remote access via SSH.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for your swift answer. I am quite a newbie here, so that is why TeamViewer is much easier for my team to operate with. Since the server is behind a router with firewall, the ssh option will only work if the server gets a fixed ip address I assume; which in turn will presume manual setup of firewall of the router?

Comment: Both are built upon the same base. "stable" depends mostly upon what you decide to do with it. I gently suggest you try both and test both thoroughly before deploying. One will be a clear winner for you...but we don't know which one that will be.

Comment: @user535733 yes that makes sense. Until now we have only worked with xubuntu desktop and we have come across issues during sudo apt upgrade. Some systems froze during the upgrade and thus leaving the grub boot loader in a total mess. This caused us to send a support personnel onsite to repair the boot loader which leads to additional costs for us.

Comment: Systems freezing during upgrade is very unusual, and worth troubleshooting. In well over a decade with all my systems, I've seen such a freeze only once...and that was a mistake I did to myself.

Comment: @user535733 I see. So there might be some hardware issues that might have caused this the freeze during upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you share your experience with us?

No, personal experience is not objective enough to argue using it on Ask Ubuntu.

> Which one is more stable (less freezing) for production environment?

Anyway, I’ll provide a generic note. Software contains errors in general (even if it’s stable mostly), so running less software means a lower probability of getting into an error (and also reduced load). The Server edition contains far less software than the Desktop one. If you don’t need GUI, don’t run it.

> Our end customer won't need to ever login onto the server since it will be running without a monitor and without input devices. We will remote control the server via teamviewer/anydesk.

This looks like a typical task for an Ubuntu Server. Remote control of Linux servers is generally done using SSH (through VPN, if needed) which is built into Ubuntu. TeamViewer and AnyDesk are also pieces of software that can contain bugs.

Comment: That is the most comprehensive answer so far. All your points make perfectly sense! Thank you so much for your honest answer!